# constructor is giving me arguments lists differ in length

Tags: java

so i'm trying to do

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int numEach = 3;
  int boatSize = 2;
  if(args.length > 1)
  {
    numEach = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    boatSize = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
  }
  arrayCan[0] = numEach;
  arrayCan[1] = 0;
  arrayMis[0] = numEach;
  arrayMis[1] = 0;
  RiverCrossingPuzzle puzzle = new RiverCrossingPuzzle (numEach, boatSize);
}
```

but it saying the argument doesn't accept 2 ints. so do i also write

```
public RiverCrossingPuzzle (numEach, boatSize)
{
 this.numEach = numEach;
 this.boatSize = boatSize;
}
```

above before the main function? 
i'm supposed to construct based on input from the command line and I can't take input without a main. So can someone help me with what I need to fix?

Comment: arguments must have a type.  this: `RiverCrossingPuzzle (numEach, boatSize)` is not java

Comment: That's unclear, maybe you could edit to clarify

Comment: Your constructor won't compile - you need to define it like `public RiverCrossingPuzzle(int numEach, int boatSize)`. Is that what your question is? Or is that just a typo? If that's your question, I highly recommend reading through a few Java tutorials before continuing any further.

Comment: What's the definition of your `RiverCrossingPuzzle` class? Is `main()` part of it? Also, perhaps `boatSize` should be initialized to `args[2]` instead of `args[3]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try adding types to the constructor (which is required by java):

here is an example

```
public Blammy(int xxx, int qqq)
{
    this.xxx = xxx;
    this.qqq = qqq;
}
```

Comment: do I need to initiate the ints before hand?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "initiate the ints".  All class variables are initialized in java.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. The ints are parameters to the function. The method signiture pretty much just says that this method needs two parameters to work, and they are both integers. They are assigned the values you give them, when making the method call.